# Gunicorn, error with Django: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'store'"

Tags: python, django, linux, bash, gunicorn

The server uses Ubuntu 20.4

How looks my **main** folder:
[image]

In **src** folder I have all Django structure:
[image]
diasmart folder here is the project folder (contains settings.py, wsgi.py...)

**My apps in settings.py**

```py
...
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # My apps
    'store.apps.StoreConfig',
    'orders.apps.OrdersConfig',
    'profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig',
]
```

**My wsgi:**

```py
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'diasmart.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**gunicorn_config.py** (main/gunicorn_config.py):

```py
command = '/root/DiaStore/env/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/root/usr/bin/python'
bind = '127.0.0.1:8001'
workers = 2
user = 'root'
limit_request_fields = 32000
limit_request_field_size = 0
raw_env = 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=src.diasmart.settings'
```

In **bin** folder (main/bin), I have "**start_gunicorn.sh**" file:
(DiaStore its the name of the main folder)

```py
#/bin/bash
source /root/DiaStore/env/bin/activate
exec gunicorn -c "/root/DiaStore/gunicorn_config.py" src.diasmart.wsgi
```

**I wrote in terminal (DiaStore is the opened folder)**:

```sh
source ./bin/start_gunicorn.sh
```

**I got:**

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/DiaStore/src/diasmart/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/root/DiaStore/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 116, in create
    mod = import_module(mod_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'store'
```

If I delete all apps from settings.INSTALLED_APPS - the server works..

Comment: Can you please give us a look at your `store` application directory?

Comment: Just a django app, if I comment in installed apps 'store.apps.StoreConfig', the error will be like 'No module named 'orders'' (or profiles)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QQBk-hnLwLeVBS4ywWIriU96qxuC7FyP/view?usp=sharing